# Run the script after error in Laravel

Tags: php, api, laravel, twitter

I want am using API of Twitter and I am getting the error no 202 and 32 and getting some error massage.

I want to continue the script after getting the error .

Is there any way in Laravel to do this

Comment: `try-catch`? why not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the Twitter API is throwing an exception.. You must catch it and continue executing the script.

```
try {
   $twitterApi->aMethod($someParams);
} catch (Twitter_Exception $e) {
   // some log of the error message
}

// continue the script here
```